# How to join two tables based on some criteria?

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have two tables:

1. `Customer_Master`
   Columns - cust_id,Date_of_birth
   There are 100 rows in the table
2. `Date_became_member`
   Columns - Date_became_member
   There are 1000 rows in the table with repetition.

These two tables do not have any common key.

Now I want to join this two tables where my date from table 2 will 
have 6000 days. During join if it finds the gap of 6000 days it should stop the procedure for the current cust_id.

I am trying with the below code but is not getting desired output.

```
select a.*, b.Date_became_member
from Customer_Master as a 
    ,Date_became_member as b
where b.Date_became_member - a.Date_of_birth = 6000
```

I am using SAS\SQL.My objective is simulate data.For this I have created above tables using random date .Now I want to tag date in which a customer become member by some random date.But the condition is there should be at least 16 years gap between date_of_birth and Date_became_member.

```
Table 1 - Customer_Master

cust_id           date_of_birth  
10013             1970/02/21  
10015             1989/11/14  
10016             1979/02/05  
10017             1986/05/26

Table 2 - Date_became_member

Date_became_member  
1986/03/25  
1992/11/21  
1994/01/24  
1998/11/21  
2004/01/24  
2001/08/25  
1995/07/07  
1979/02/21  
1997/06/07  
2005/02/21  
2006/09/11

Desired output

cust_id      date_of_birth           Date_became_member  
10013        1970/02/21               1986/03/25  
10015        1989/11/14               2006/09/11  
10016        1979/02/05               1995/07/07  
10017        1986/05/26               2004/01/24
```

The logic is that there should be at least a gap of 16 years between date_of_birth and Date_became_member and if it finds a gap of 16 years 
from any of the dates in table 2 it should take only that date not any other day which has a gap of 16 years or more.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your problem. Why do you want to join two tables, that have no common id or something. And what is it about 6000 days? That's more than 16 years. Can you give examples of the data in the tables and what output you want?

Comment: Edit you question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using SAS\SQL.My objective is simulate data.For this I have created above tables using random date .Now I want to tag date in which a customer become member by some random date.But the condition is there should be at least 16 years gap between date_of_birth and Date_became_member.

Comment: Again: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the `Date_became_member` has a column that links it to a particular row or rows in `Customer_Master` you cannot join them meaningfully.  To establish a connection between rows that have a definite connection we most often use a foreign key relationship(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for more information).

If the `Date_became_member` does have a `cust_id` column like the `Customer_Master` table then your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT cm.cust_id 
     , cm.date_of_birth
     , dbm.Date_became_member
  FROM Customer_Master AS cm 
  JOIN Date_became_member AS dbm
    ON cm.cust_id = dbm.cust_id
 WHERE dbm.Date_became_member - CM.Date_of_birth = 6000
```

If there are no other columns in the `Date_became_member` table then I would suggest that it's usefulness is extremely limited ad a redesign may well be in order.

If you do want a join that shows every row in `Customer_Master` joined to every row `Date_became_member` in  then you need a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
     SELECT cm.cust_id 
          , cm.date_of_birth
          , dbm.Date_became_member
       FROM Customer_Master AS cm 
 CROSS JOIN Date_became_member AS dbm
      WHERE dbm.Date_became_member - CM.Date_of_birth = 6000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point of your question is how to find the FIRST date that meets your 16 year old requirement.  To do that you need to group the data by customer.  To find the 16 year interval you can use the `INTNX()` function.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
    select cust_id,dob,date_became_member
    from customer_master
    left join date_became_member
    on date_became_member > intnx('year',dob,16,'same')
    group by 1,2
    having date_became_member= min(date_became_member)
  ;
quit;
```